# MATLAB coding problem

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

Hey guys, I got this error message when I tried to trigger the function below. Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

```
>> changeYuv('tilt.yuv',352,288,1:40,40);
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
    Error in ==> changeYuv at 32
            j=histogram(imgYuv(:,:,1,k+1));

>> [x,y,z,a]=size(imgYuv)
x =
   288
y =
   352
z =
     3
a =
    40
```

The source code:

```
function [imgYuv, S]= changeYuv(fileName, width, height, idxFrame, nFrames) 
% load RGB movie [0, 255] from YUV 4:2:0 file

fileId = fopen(fileName, 'r');

subSampleMat = [1, 1; 1, 1];
nrFrame = length(idxFrame);

for f = 1 : 1 : nrFrame
    % search fileId position
    sizeFrame = 1.5 * width * height;
    fseek(fileId, (idxFrame(f) - 1) * sizeFrame, 'bof');

    % read Y component
    buf = fread(fileId, width * height, 'uchar');
    imgYuv(:, :, 1,f) = reshape(buf, width, height).';

    % read U component
    buf = fread(fileId, width / 2 * height / 2, 'uchar');
    imgYuv(:, :, 2,f) = kron(reshape(buf, width / 2, height / 2).', subSampleMat); % reshape and upsample

    % read V component
    buf = fread(fileId, width / 2 * height / 2, 'uchar');
    imgYuv(:, :, 3,f) = kron(reshape(buf, width / 2, height / 2).', subSampleMat); % reshape and upsample

    %histogram difference of Y component
    for k=1:(nFrames-1)
        h=histogram(imgYuv(:,:,1,k));
        j=histogram(imgYuv(:,:,1,k+1));
        X=abs(h-j)/256;
        S(k)=sum(X);
    end
end
fclose(fileId);
```

Comment: please run `[x,y,z,a] = size(imgYuv)` for us somewhere above the error line and tell us the value of `a`.

Comment: Hi Mark. I've added in the size of imgYuv. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every iteration of the outer loop, you appear to be growing `imgYuv` by one in the 4th dimension, starting from empty.  But your inner loop always loops from `1` to `nFrames-1`.  Therefore, it would seem to me like you're trying to access beyond the extent of `imgYuv`.

On an unrelated note, growing an array like this is typically very slow.  You're much better off initialising `imgYuv` before you start, i.e. `imgYuv = zeros([height,width,3,nFrames])`.

Comment: Yup, you are right. After I initialise the matrix, the problem never comes back again. Thank you!

Comment: @Yoursclark: You seem to be recalculating the histogram on every single iteration of the outer loop, and overwriting the previous results, which is a bit of a waste.  Why not just move the histogram loop to the end of the function.